# How to get dates from task separately with regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to pull the dates from this task:

```
(C) 2015-02-18 {2013.06.04} Check Alibaba for suppliers +Company @Computer due:2015-02-17
```

Currently, this is how I'm doing it:

```
def split_task(task_id):

     todo_list = get_todo_list()

     task = todo_list[int(task_id)-1]

     split_task = task.split(" ")

     task_id = split_task[0]

     task_dict = {}
     new_split_task = []

     for index,s in enumerate(split_task):

         flag = ""

         if re.search('[^:][0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])',split_task[index]):

             task_dict['creation_date']=split_task[index]
             flag=1

         if re.search('[:]([0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]))',split_task[index]):

             task = split_task[index]
             task_dict['due_date'] = task[4:]
             flag=1

        if re.search('({\d{4}.\d{2}.\d{2}})',split_task[index]):

             task_dict['mit'] = split_task[index]
             flag=1
```

I can successfully grab the bracketed date, and the due: date, but I can't figure out how to get the normal date in a way that doesn't capture the others.

Answer (score 2):

you can just match the spaces in your expression:

```
# with the curly braces
re.search(r'\{\d{4}.\d{2}.\d{2}\}', text)

# with the spaces
re.search(r' \d{4}.\d{2}.\d{2} ', text)

# if you want to get the date, then capture it with brackets:
date = re.findall(r' (\d{4}.\d{2}.\d{2}) ', text)
print(date) # list of dates
```

Note that you should escape curly braces if you want to match a curly brace in your text.

Also note also the difference between `"\n"` and `r"\n"`. The latter is a backslash followed by the letter n, not a newline.

Comment: So how is it failing? Note, I did an edit because the code has some parts missing.

Comment: It's just not catching the date. And I can't check it in regexr.com I will try again later tonight

Comment: What do you mean with that? Does it not return a match object? In your code example you're not doing anything with the returned match object.

Comment: I'm getting `None` as the match for everything that passes.

Comment: Yes, I'm filtering the match with `if` and then adding the result of the match to the correct place in `task_dict`. And also, the edit you gave with `re.findall()` didn't work for me either.

Comment: Well, I see now, you're splitting the task before applying a regular expression. That's a bit unusual, especially since you're using `search` rather than `match`. In that case, use `re.match(r'\d{4}.\d{2}.\d{2}$', text)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96922/discussion-between-roeland-and-zenmode).

Answer (score 0):

I made this work by adding an extra AND NOT to the filter, like so:

```
if re.search('[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])',split_task[index]) and not re.search('[:]([0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]))',split_task[index]):

    task_dict['creation_date']=split_task[index]
    flag=1
```